# Confidence interval for Roc curve in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, roc, auc, proc-r-package

I have created the code for displaying a confidence interval for the ROC curve for both Logistic and Random Forest. But I would like to have 1- specificity in the x-axis instead of specificity.
The code is

```
roc.list <- roc(test_df$extry ~ Logistic_Regression+Random_Forest)
ci.list <- lapply(roc.list, ci.se, specificities = seq(0, 1, l = 10))

dat.ci.list <- lapply(ci.list, function(ciobj) 
  data.frame(x = as.numeric(rownames(ciobj)),
             lower = ciobj[, 1],
             upper = ciobj[, 3]))

p <- ggroc(roc.list,legacy.axes=TRUE) + theme_minimal() + geom_abline(slope=1, intercept = 1, linetype = "dashed", alpha=0.7, color = "grey") + coord_equal()

for(i in 1:3) {
  p <- p + geom_ribbon(
    data = dat.ci.list[[i]],
    aes(x = x, ymin = lower, ymax = upper),
    fill = i + 1,
    alpha = 0.2,
    inherit.aes = F) 
} 

p
```

And the output: **[image: ThE CI is weird.]**
Any idea?

Comment: Maybe try `aes(x = 1 - x, ymin = lower, ymax = upper),` instead of `aes(x = x, ymin = lower, ymax = upper),`

Comment: Works as a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the `ggroc` function from the `pROC` package.

When you run `ggroc` with `legacy.axes=TRUE`, the `ggplot` function is called with the following aesthetics:

```
aes(x = "1-specificity", y = "sensitivity")
```

As identified by [@Allan Cameron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12500315/allan-cameron) in the comments, you need to specify compatible aesthetics that specify 1-specificity in x:

```
p <- p + geom_ribbon(
     data = dat.ci.list[[i]],
     aes(x = 1 - x, ymin = lower, ymax = upper),
     fill = i + 1,
     alpha = 0.2,
     inherit.aes = F)
```